# How to get the whole text in one line from the same html tags inside a specific HTML tag?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have a pretty long HTML file that looks like:

```html
<div><nobr>
<span>ABC</span>
<span>DEF</span>
<span>GHI</span>
</nobr></div>

<div><nobr>
<span>100</span>
</nobr></div>

<div><nobr>
<span>JKL</span>
<span>MNO</span>
<span>PQR</span>
</nobr></div>

<div><nobr>
<span>101</span>
</div></nobr>'
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')
nobr_tags = soup.select('nobr')
```

How can I get the whole text inside `span` tags in a `nobr` HTML tag **in one line** using BeautifulSoup?

I want to get is:

```
ABCDEFGHI, 100, JKLMNOPQR, 101, ...
```

But what I got was:

```
ABC, DEF, GHI, 100, JKL, MNO, PQR, 101, ...
```

Some `<nobr>` tags have 2, 3, or 4 `<span>` tags inside a `<nobr>` tag.
No matter how many span tags there are in a nobr tag, I want to get all the text inside a `<nobr>` tag in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator-expression to [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the tags with a `,`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div>
   <nobr>
      <span>ABC</span>
      <span>DEF</span>
      <span>GHI</span>
   </nobr>
</div>
<div>
   <nobr>
      <span>100</span>
   </nobr>
</div>
<div>
   <nobr>
      <span>JKL</span>
      <span>MNO</span>
      <span>PQR</span>
   </nobr>
</div>
<div>
   <nobr>
      <span>101</span>
</div>
</nobr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

print(
    ", ".join(x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select("nobr"))
)
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHI, 100, JKLMNOPQR, 101
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
It works like magic! : )